# How to add lm.augment output to my original dataset

Tags: r, lm

I'm using the following R code in power query, and it's working well to provide me the studentized residuals that I use to flag outliers in a big dataset :

As output, I get the 'df' object containing the col "group" + the augment output including the studentized residuals column.

My objective is obtaining the original dataset + the studentized column to avoid having 2 big tables (my original table has 20M of rows, not easy to have 2 tables with such big size ...).
Thanks a lot for your help !

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(broom)

    dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
    dataset$perf <- as.numeric(dataset$perf)
    dataset$factor1 <- as.factor(dataset$factor1)
    dataset$factor2 <- as.factor(dataset$factor2)

    df <- dataset %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(unique_factor1 = n_distinct(factor1), unique_factor1 = n_distinct(factor1), var = 
    var(perf)) %>% 
    filter( unique_factor1 != 1 & unique_factor2 != 1 & var != 0 ) %>%
    do(cbind(group = .$group, lm(perf ~ factor1 + factor2, data = .) %>% augment))

group   perf   factor1  Factor2
1       32         1     1
1       44         1     2
1       58         1     3
1       76         2     1
1       73         2     2
1       37         2     3
1       52         3     1
1       78         3     2
1       60         3     3
2       93         1     1
2       78         1     2
2       25         1     3
2       97         2     1
2       85         2     2
2       60         2     3
2       70         3     1
2       62         3     2
2       95         3     3
```

Comment: See `?augment`, it should already give you both the original data and the added columns. You may need to pass a `data` argument. Alternatively, you can extend that `cbind()` call to add more columns, although one should probably use `data.frame` and not `cbind`. A reproducible example would make it more likely to receive a useful answer.

Comment: @Axeman, thanks four reply !
I just added a piece of my dataset representing my case